# Is there a way to link my Google Reader shared items to Facebook updates?

Tags: facebook, google-reader

Whenever I share something in *Google Reader* it should appear in my *Facebook* updates as well.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Headover to your facebook profile -> Wall -> click on settings -> stories posted by you -> Imported stores -> Google Reader.

[image]

Add your public URL, and that's it. You can get your public URL from [Google Reader Shared Settings](http://www.google.com/reader/view/user/-/state/com.google/broadcast#friends-manager-page).

Comment: Unfortunately this feature has be discontinued: "The Imported Stories feature is no longer available. Most of the sites supported by this feature now allow you to publish stories to Facebook directly from the site."