# Facebook is slow to post imported sites like Delicious and Google Reader

Tags: facebook, delicious

On Facebook, I set my settings to pull posts (saved items) from Delicious and Google Reader.    It's set to show that I posted on either of the sites as part of my regular Facebook feed.

However, for the most part it doesn't post any new saved items from either of those feeds.  It seems rather random as to when it decides to read that there are new items on either of those services, and then for them to actually show up on my Facebook.  When it does appear, it seems to take weeks (if not months) worth of saved items and posts them.  By the way, I do save bookmarks on both Delicious and Google Reader on a daily basis.

My question is: **Why is Facebook so slow to pull any newly saved items from Delicious and Google Reader?**

It seems that the one way I can get Facebook to see that there's something new is to manually update it by going to Options->Settings->Stories Posted by you->Imported Sites, and clicking on either of the links to Delicious/Google Reader, and clicking on 'Update Now'.

Related:
[Google reader shared items in Facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1290/google-reader-shared-items-in-facebook)

Comment: The imported sites feature has been discontinued with this message: "The Imported Stories feature is no longer available. Most of the sites supported by this feature now allow you to publish stories to Facebook directly from the site."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook's feed pulling system, to be frank, sucks. It's gotten slower and slower for no apparent reason, though I assume that the upsurge in users has resulted in large increases in server load. That's the only reason I can think of.

Comment: I think you might be right.  Facebook feed pulling system is just horrible.  Considering they bought FriendFeed, they should be doing a better job.

Comment: The FriendFeed acquisition was mostly about the team behind the product, unfortunately. Facebook has integrated some FriendFeed-like features into its own site since the acquisition, but for the most part it seems that the former FriendFeeders have been put to work on other projects. Too bad, really; FF had a wonderful engine for pulling feeds.