# Importing RSS items into Facebook

Tags: facebook, rss, blog, import

I want to import my (Wordpress-based) blog entries into my Facebook account to share them with my FB friends.

FB already has a built-in function to create Notes based on RSS items. The problem is that it's not automatically refreshing for me, ever. Even though FB claims that it was refreshed on a recent date/time, I don't get new Notes unless I go in and manually trigger a refresh. That's a pain.

So, I'd like to know what the best way to get my content into FB is. Is there some trick to making the built-in FB importer work properly? Or are there better 3rd-party tools that I could use and avoid the headache?

Comment: similar to: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4751/facebook-is-slow-to-post-imported-sites-like-delicious-and-google-reader

Comment: @sunpech: It's similar, but I'm not sure if it's a duplicate. It reads "pulling items from Google Reader"; is that via RSS? The question doesn't mention that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it will work for you but I just found an app on Facebook called RSS Graffiti which lets you do pretty much what you asked above.  I'm using it for a Fan page wall and my Classified ads based Wordpress site.  Now my users post an ad on my site and they get double the exposure.

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I want; I'll give it a try as soon as I can.

Comment: Answer outdated... http://www.scribblelive.com/important-notice-rss-graffiti/