# How can I import my Google Reader shared items into Facebook?

Tags: facebook, google-reader

Now that Facebook has discontinued the imported sites feature what is the best way to have my Google Reader shared items show in my Facebook news feed?

I did find [Google reader shared items in Facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1290/google-reader-shared-items-in-facebook) but that is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the [RSS Graffiti](http://www.facebook.com/RSS.Graffiti) application and have used that to import my Google Reader Shared Items RSS feed.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to http://www.google.com/reader/shared/[your.username] and copy the URL of the Atom feed of your Google Reader Shared Items. It looks something like this: `http://www.google.com/reader/public/atom/user/[number]/state/com.google/broadcast`
- Go to your Facebook profile
- Click on Notes → See all → Edit import settings
- Enter the URL of the feed

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that this feature has since been removed.